# DDS plugin for GIMP

Tags: gtk, gimp, gtk-2

So I'm tyring to install [this](https://code.google.com/p/gimp-dds/) DDS plug in for gimp. I've done it before, but on this fresh install of Ubuntu I'm failing.

I extract the archive, then type make. This results in:

```
joel@Zetes:~/gimp-dds-3.0.1$ make
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
Package gimp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gimp-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gimp-2.0' found
[CC]    dds.c
dds.c:27:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [dds.o] Error 1
joel@Zetes:~/gimp-dds-3.0.1$
```

So I'm missing package gtk+-2.0. This I can't find in either the software centre or with Synaptic.

Answer (score 5):

The answers are in the error messages

- gtk+-2.0

  > Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc' to the
  >   PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'gtk+-2.0' found

  therefore

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
  ```

  Why?

  ```
  % apt-file search gtk+-2.0.pc
  libgtk2.0-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtk+-2.0.pc

  % apt-cache search libgtk2 | grep dev
  libgtk2.0-cil-dev - CLI binding for the GTK+ toolkit 2.12
  libgtk2.0-dev - development files for the GTK+ library

  % apt-file search --regex gtk/gtk.h$
  libgtk-3-dev: /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h
  libgtk2.0-dev: /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h
  ```
- gimp-2.0

  > Package gimp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  >   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gimp-2.0.pc'

  therefore

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev
  ```

  Why?

  ```
  % apt-file search gimp-2.0.pc        
  libgimp2.0-dev: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/gimp-2.0.pc

  % apt-cache search libgimp | grep dev
  libgimp2.0-dev - Headers and other files for compiling plugins for GIMP
  ```